# Test push notifications with a non published ios/android app?

Tags: android, ios, debugging, firebase, push-notification

The first version of my app already needs some push notifications. I'm trying to use firebase for it, but when trying to configure the ios app, i'm being asked for a ios bundle id which apparently I only can get publishing my app in the app store, I'm I right?. Is there any way to configure and test push notifications with a non publish ios app?.

Comment: The bundle id is just the app id, you yourself entered the app id when you created the Xcode project for your app.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not right. You can find your bundle id in Xcode. Go to your project  settings, select your target (probably named the same as your app) and you will find the bundle id on the "General" tab under Identity. 
It is the same as the App ID you or Xcode already created under "Certificates, IDs & Profiles" -> "Identifiers" -> "App IDs" in your Apple developer account.